# maxLengthEnforced isn't being enforced

Tags: flutter

Inside my TextFormField, I have a maxLength of 35, and the maxLengthEnforced (which by default is true) isn't being enforced, when the user writes something between the text, it just pushes the characters to the right and deletes the ones in the end to meet the 35 maxLength.

This is what I'm using:

```
TextFormField(
  focusNode: _currentFocus,
  textInputAction: _textInputAction ?? TextInputAction.done,
  onFieldSubmitted: _textInputAction == TextInputAction.done
    ? (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()
    : (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
  initialValue: _initialValue,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    counterText: "",
    hintText: _hintText,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  ),
  maxLines: 1,
  maxLength: 35,
  maxLengthEnforced: true,
  onChanged: _onChanged,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
);
```

Comment: i see nothing wrong here try close the app and restart it and see

Comment: I even closed the emulator and it still doesn't work. @RidhaRezzag